# write double qoutes with razor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Im a newbie with razor and i having that problem. How can do it?
I need to write an id attribute if a condition has met. Here what I've tried:

```
<select name="@LabelName" @if(LabelName.Contains("CHECK_STATUS")) { var id = "string\'"; @id }>//it prints string&#39;.

<select name="@LabelName" @if(LabelName.Contains("CHECK_STATUS")) { ViewBag.id = "id='check'"; @ViewBag.id }>//same problem id=&quoute;check&quoute;
```

Suggestion? I need to print that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you end up in this tag soup (I guess, like everyone else, you didn't use view models)? You have HTML helpers that are designed to generate dropdowns. You know, things like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor()
```

But if you want to continue to swim in the soup you could use the ternary operator to conditionally output the id property:

```
<select name="@LabelName"@Html.Raw(LabelName.Contains("CHECK_STATUS") ? string.Format(" id=\"{0}\"", id) : "")>
```

or if the id is in the ViewBag:

```
<select name="@LabelName"@Html.Raw(LabelName.Contains("CHECK_STATUS") ? string.Format(" id=\"{0}\"", ViewBag.id) : "")>
```

Notice how you should use the Html.Raw helper to avoid the value being HTML encoded (which is what the `@` function does by default)